# Equivalent to "continue" in Python's "with"-statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, continue

I found [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) in the Python docs:

> `continue` may only occur syntactically nested in a `for` or `while` loop,
>   but not nested in a function or class definition or `finally` clause
>   within that loop. It continues with the next cycle of the nearest
>   enclosing loop.

As the `continue`-instruction is not made for the `with`-statement: Is there any alternative other than restructuring the code appropriately?

Example code (the way I want it to be working):

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    if someConditionNotMet(f):
        continue  # "exit" with-statement
    # do lots of stuff
```

Of course I could write the `# do lots of stuff`-code inside an `else`-branch, however, this would only make the code less readable, if there are already two or three nested `if`-`else`-branches. In a function I could simply use `return` and in a `while`- or `for`-loop the beforementioned `continue`. Is there an equivalent to `continue` in a Python's `with`-statement?

Well, you could also replace the `continue` by a `break` in the text above, logically it would be the same in a `with`-statement as the code inside it is only executed once, anyway... (but the `break` only works for `for`- and `while`-loops, either).

Comment: A `with` statement isn't a looping construct, so `continue` doesn't really make sense in that context. You can't use `continue` in an `if` either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yeah, I noticed this just after posting my question. See the last paragraph which I've added about it.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a too-clever-by-half use of a context manager to add exception management support to `with` blocks provided as an answer in the question this is a duplicate of; it certainly does what you want. That said, I'd say that the _best_ approach is to structure your code to have a separate function in use and `return`.

Comment: @fredtantini: You are right. Voted for close. **Thanks** for the link! I did not find this, no matter which search keys I tried :/ So basically there's no such equivalent... Only way is to restructure the code in an appropriate way :/ Well, not the answer I hoped to find, but the one I feared to get :D